# Coded UI Environment.CurrentDirectory/Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly pointing to temp folder

Tags: coded-ui-tests

We have coded ui(VS 2013) installed on server and integrated with TFS.Multiple users from different projects have access to server and they create their projects.We have a weird issue for few users. when they execute any of below code, it points to

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\13\projectname\username_servername 2015-05-20 16_33_58\Out.

System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(".\\") + @"\projectname\"
```

or

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

or

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
```

I am expecting it to point to local path where we have downloaded scripts say

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\folder1\projectname\username_servername 2015-05-20 16_33_58\Out
```

As a result, when running script, its failing with exception

```
"An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code.  Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\13\projectname\\EnvironmentConfigfile.xml'.".
```

We have `EnvironmentConfigfile.xml` file in `C:\Users\username\Desktop\folder1\projectname\`

I compared settings file with the login that dont have issue and everything is same. Not sure what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think when codedui runs it copies the deployment files to a temp directory and creates the testResult with all the resources it gathers during the test in the temp directory - only after the test ends the files are copied to the designated location.

use a testsettings file and deploy the configuration file you need for your test.

tell me if you need instructions how to do that

Comment: Can you please let me know instructions for that. Point to note is that it works for few users. Issue is for few login's. I suspect its user specific settings?